# Xamarin Effect affecting other controls

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am experiencing a weird bug where a Custom effect would affect other Controls as well while i am only targeting one specific control. I was able to reproduce the behavior in a small test project. What i am trying to achieve is to change the color of a specific entry control. It does work but when navigating back to the previous page the effect affects other controls as well while i only want the specific effect to affect a specific control. I also only add the effect to the specific Entry by using its Effects list from xaml.

(note i am using the standard forms navigation page for navigating defined in my app.xaml like this.

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2"
             x:Class="App2.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Entry></Entry>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"  Text="navigate"></Button>
        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked2"  Text="navigate to other"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

CodeBehind of MainPage.xaml

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Test());
    }

    private void Button_Clicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Test2());
    }
}
```

Test.Xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2"
             x:Class="App2.Test">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Entry>
            <Entry.Effects>
                <local:EntryLineColorEffect></local:EntryLineColorEffect>
            </Entry.Effects>
        </Entry>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Test2.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.Test2">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="test 2" />
            <Entry>
            </Entry>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

EntryLineColorEffect (forms project)

```
public class EntryLineColorEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public EntryLineColorEffect() : base("Prolang.EntryLineColorEffect")
    {
    }
}
```

EntryLineColorEffect (Android project)

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Prolang")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(EntryLineColorEffect), "EntryLineColorEffect")]
namespace App2.Droid.Effects
{
    class EntryLineColorEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        EditText control;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            control = Control as EditText;
            UpdateLineColor();
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            control = null;
        }

        private void UpdateLineColor()
        {
            if (control != null)
            {
                control.Background.SetColorFilter(Color.DarkMagenta.ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

some screenshots that make it more clear

[image: MainPage]

[image: TestPage]
The entry does get the Magenta color which is good

[image: Test2Page]

But when navigating back and then navigating to the Test2 page that entry is also getting the Magenta color which for me is undesired behavior (and i do not know why it is hapenning). So what should i do to avoid this behavior?

Comment: delete ```xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2"``` in your *test2.xaml* code. No need to use this here.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Xamarin! (haha, it can be tricky)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end someone on the Xamarin comunity forum was able to answer my question.

=> 
Effect won't affect other controls which haven't attached that effect. It seems `Background.SetColorFilter(Color.DarkMagenta.ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);` changes the global Entry's underline's color. The entry displayed later after this setting will apply this behavior. So your Test2's Entry still has an attacted style. Use `Background.Mutate().SetColorFilter(Color.DarkMagenta.ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);` instead to correct that:

```
EditText control;

protected override void OnAttached()
{
    control = Control as EditText;
    UpdateLineColor();
}

protected override void OnDetached()
{
    control = null;
}

private void UpdateLineColor()
{
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.Background.Mutate().SetColorFilter(Color.DarkMagenta.ToAndroid(), Android.Graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
    }
}
```